# arrays and pointers arithmetic

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Suppose an array `int a[10]`.

Why we can't do `a=a+1` ? but the same is valid with a pointer variable.

```
int  *ptr = a;

ptr = a+1;
```

How are both scenarios seen practically?

Comment: we cannot move the location in memory of the 'a' array.  However, we can change an external pointer to that array to point to the second element of the array

Comment: Because array and pointers are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because array locations are constant.

You can't change the value of `a`, since that represents the starting address of the array. Moving it doesn't make any sense.

With `int *ptr;` your variable `ptr` is just a single pointer and can of course be set to point to anywhere you like.

There's no contradiction here. It's a little like with functions, the name of a function evaluates to its address (called "a function pointer") but you can't assign to that either.

Answer (score -1):

Because Array name is constant pointer pointing to its first element.You cannot change the value of constant variables,i,e what the const keyword is used for.

```
int a[10];      //here a (array variable is Const i,e you Cannot a=a+1)
int* const p=&a[0]; //here Also Same,Now p is Const i,e you Cannot p=p+1.
```

But Here:

```
int* pp=&a[0];//Here pp=pp+1 will work, Because pp is not Const.
```

Comment: "Array name is constant pointer" - no, it's an array. The fact that it can't change doesn't mean it's `const`.

Comment: Internally it act like a constant, It has to be Because it should always represent the Base Address of its First Element.Am Pretty Sure About it.

Comment: I see you are sure about it, but you're still wrong. All I am saying is that it's not a `const` pointer. A `const` pointer would look like `int *const p;`. An array is an array and is not a pointer. It can't be modified, but **not** because it's a `const`, rather because it's an array. Neither `const`s nor array can be modified, but **that does not mean that something which cannot be modified is a `const`.**

Answer (score -2):

You *can* if the array is a function argument

```
#include <stdio.h>

int rval(int a[10]) {
    a = a + 1;
    return a[0];
    }

int main(){
    int a[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    printf ("%d\n", rval(a));
    return 0;
}
```

Program output

```
1
```

Comment: of course, the function argument is NOT the array, but rather a copy of the pointer to the array.  the pointer copy can be changed, but not the actual location of the beginning of the array in memory

Comment: Agreed, but it answers the question as asked.

Comment: Hi,But when we passes an array to a function,it automatically converts to a pointer.Hence it'll tun fine.Right?

Comment: In this case, `a` is not an array, it's a pointer.